# error using npm to install oracledb

Tags: node.js, oracle, rest, npm, oracle-sqldeveloper

tried installing node oracledb on windows 7 and it gave this error
[npm install oracledb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5s5s.png)

I followed all the steps on this tutorial [Installing node-oracledb on Microsoft Windows](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-931127)
but it doesn't work, can you gauys please help me

Answer (score 0):

From the error message (English part), I guess you installed the wrong Node.js package. Say, your Windows machine is X64 and you installed the X86 32-bit Node.js. Or, vice versa.